# Responsive Div Height (Padding-Bottom Percent) Fraction of a Pixel

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, percentage

```
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.large {
width:66.66666667%;
padding-bottom:33.3333333%;
background-color:red;
float:left;
border:2px solid white;
}

.small {
width: 16.666666667%;
padding-bottom:16.66666667%;
background-color:green;
float:left;
border:1px solid white;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMMrLo

I'm struggling with a problem where I have a responsive, percentage based layout with one larger box and a load of smaller boxes I want to wrap around it. When resizing every other pixel looks fine but the smaller divs stop wrapping around the large one at 50% of resolutions.

Not sure if it's a browser issue so if it's working for you in codepen here's a screenshot of the problem itself.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEQHu.jpg

Anyone know any quick fixes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off I highly recommend using CSS3's calc() function to solve such things...

```
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.large {
width:calc(100%/3 * 2);
padding-bottom:calc(100%/3 - 1px);
background:linear-gradient(to bottom right, #bbb, #aaa);
float:left;
}

.small {
width: calc(100%/6);
padding-bottom:calc(100%/6);
background:linear-gradient(to bottom right, #222, #333);
float:left;
}
```

This should fix your issues, try playing around with that '-1px' part, there might be an 1px gap somewhere...

CODEPEN: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/obboeg

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be caused by browsers doing pixel layout instead of calculating to fractions of a pixel. So there will, in some cases like this, always be a uncertainty of ±1px or less. If such a small value will break your layout, the only way to fix it (other than changing your layout to use flexbox or something) is to subtract a pixel to make it always be smaller than too big.

```
padding-bottom:33.2%;
```

Or:

```
padding-bottom:calc(33.3333333% - 1px);
```

As The Faxemaxe [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34302191/2371861), you can also use division instead of insanely long decimals inside [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc).

Comment: The insanely long decimals are just outputs from SASS!

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be an issue with how the browser will round the decimals. Some will round it up and some down. When rounded up it will be too large and push everything directly below it down.

The main cause in this program seems to be the padding-bottom on the large box. If you set it to something like 33% it will work but you will have a gap sometimes. This can be fixed with a container around the divs and adding a background color like this:

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40vw;
  background-color: #aaa; 
}

.large {
  width:66.66666667%;
  padding-bottom: 33%;
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom right, #bbb, #aaa);
  float:left;
}
```

http://codepen.io/bartuc/pen/eJJeGb

Comment: Sadly in real life these actually have background images so a background color doesn't really work. I guess I'll need to do some javascript if I actually want a perfect edge like that without using flexbox.